# Errors trying to find only the number in a string?

Tags: python

Supposed to take in a string for example "Maroon 5" and then return only the number in the statement. In this case it's "5"  but I just get no output. Thank you!

```
def findNumbers(str):
    found1 = False
    found2 = False
    i = 0
    while not found1 and i<len(str):
        if str[i] in "0123456789":
            found1 = True
        else:
            i = i + 1
    if found1:
        j = 0
        while not found2 and j<len(str):
            if str[j] in "0123456789":
                found2 = False
            else:
                j = j + 1
    else:
            return 0
    istr = str[i:j]
    n = (istr)
    return n

print (findNumbers("Maroon 5"))
```

Comment: Use `str[i].isdigit()` instead of `str[i] in "0123456789"`

Comment: Later on you'll learn about `re` module for regexes and `re.match`

Comment: `findNumbers = lambda s: [e for e in s.split() if e.isdigit()]; print (findNumbers("Maroon 5"))`

Answer (score 0):

You have two important errors in your code. One is that once you've found a digit, you jump back to the start of the string:

```
j = 0
```

Instead, you want to continue from there:

```
j = i
```

The other, bigger problem is that you have an infinite loop. The second loop may continue indefinitely if `str[j]` is a digit, since setting `found2` to False does not end the loop. The code should be

```
while not found2 and j<len(str):
    if str[j] not in "0123456789":
        found2 = True
    else:
        j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
def findNumbers(str): 
for i in range(0,len(str)):
    if (str[i].isdigit()):
        print str[i]
findNumbers("Maroon 5")
```

It should print the number 5

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way: This will return a list of tuples with the numbers and their indexes

```
def findNumbers(string):
    num = '1234567890'
    return ([(string[x], x) for x in range(len(string)) if string[x] in num])
```

Comment: Alternatively .isdigit() method could be used too.